# How to tell if the product of two incidence (edges vs.vertices) matrices will be an incidence matrix

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

I'm trying to determine if there are properties of certain incidence matrices that mean that their multiple will create a valid incidence matrix, i.e., the total number of non zero entries in each row is either 2 or 0.

In the set of matrices $\mathbb{N}_{2}^{3\times3}$, there are three valid columns: $$\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}$$
Which can make $3^{3}$ possible matrices (or $4^{4}$ if the zero vector / 'missing edges' is included) but only some will multiply together to make a third valid incidence matrix.

So in all, I'd like to know if there are any ways to determine if the product of two matrices will preserve the property of being a valid incidence matrix.

Comment: Do you mean incidence matrix in a graph which is between vertices, i.e., $A_{i,j}=1 \iff $ vertex i is connected to vertex j (not between vertices and edges ?)

Comment: Not really, I'm talking about matrixes where $A_{i,j} = 1 \iff$ vertex i is connected to edge j. Each column represents an edge, and each row represents a vertex. If $A_{i,j} = 1$, then edge j is incident with row i. In this situation, these graphs have no loops, so an edge can either be incident with two vertices, or no vertices (a missing edge).

Comment: Therefore my 2nd interpretation was the good one. Something puzzles me: usually a graph hasn't the same number of vertices and edges. Therefore my question is how do you multiply 2 (rectangular in general) incidence matrices A,B ? You must first see if they have a common dimension ? No ?

Answer (score 1):

It would be highly dependent on how the edges and vertices are ordered. I am struggling a bit to see why this would be something interesting (but that doesn't mean you don't have a reason to be interested in it).

You just need to phrase your question in terms of what the rows/columns of the incidence matrix means, and what it means to multiply matrices... this will give a very convoluted combinatorial condition like "for each vertex $v_{i}$ of the first graph, let $I_{i}$ be the set of edge indices for the edges adjacent to $v_{i}$; then for each edge $e_{j}$ of the second graph, there can be at most one vertex (of the second graph) incident with $e_{j}$ whose index is in $I_{i}$; and furthermore, there must be either $0$ or $2$ edges $e_{j}$ incident with a vertex whose index is in $I_{i}$."

Comment: I wrote this answer assuming that the matrix entries are interpreted as real numbers 0/1, and not as elements of $\mathbb{F}_{2}$.